# Unity3d Chromium Embedded Framework permissions

Tags: command-line, unity, chromium

After installing the latest version of Unity3d by command-line in Ubuntu (14.04 of 15), you have this error:

```
Chromium Embedded Framework requires that the file '/opt/Unity/Editor/chrome-sandbox' is owned by root and hase permission 4755
```

How do I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add permission to Unity3d sandbox:

```
sudo chmod 4755 /opt/Unity/Editor/chrome-sandbox
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem which did not get resolved when I ran the corresponding chmod command. In my case the problem was that my /opt directory is hosted on another NTFS partition and this confused Linux file access privileges.

When I moved back my /opt to the ext4 root partition, Unity3D installed and runs fine.